# How do I validate a number against a list of valid numbers?

Tags: webforms

I want to validate a license number against a list of license numbers stored in vocabulary as taxonomy terms. The returned boolean value should then activate other form fields which are disabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [custom webform validation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-a-webform-element).

In a custom module you will need to implement `CUSTOM_MODULE_webform_element_alter` in which you will define a new validation method.

You have to implement the callback method `validate()` as it is described in the documentation above.

In your `validate` method you have to compare the submitted value with your vocabulary terms using something similar to the following code

```
// ...
$vid = 'vocabularyname';
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if($value == $term->name){
        // ... found 
    }
}
```

**About the 2nd part of you question / conditional enabling of fields**

Webform built-in conditional logic probably cannot handle it as it only depends on values and NOT validation state of another field.  Perhaps it can be done using [conditional_fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) but I have not personally tried it.

Comment: Thank you @GiorgosK. I have tried it and it throws these errors:
Undefined variable: error in Drupal\ama_form\Validate\MyValidateConstraint::validate() (line 41 of modules/custom/ama_form/src/Validate/MyValidateConstraint.php
P.S: Due to the comment limitation, I was able only to include the first line of errors

Comment: @FareedFattal include in your question what you have tried and what errors you get, make sure you include all the relevant code and perhaps someone can spot the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've added the error message to my question.

Comment: @FareedFattal please include all the relevant code as it might be useful

Comment: Thank you @GiorgosK. I was having an undefined variable error but got it resolved. Sorry about that!

Comment: Great glad you got it resolved.